# How to add numbers value in ONE input text?

Tags: javascript, operator-keyword, tracker

I have coded and used for loop but only works if I use multiple Input text.

**I want to achieve:**

Every time I input number on one Input text and hit the buttons "add" or "deduct, I want the total below will keep updating while adding or deducting.

```
let total = 0;

    for(var i=0; i<priceTrim.length; i++){
        if(parseInt(priceTrim[i].value))
        total += parseInt(priceTrim[i].value);
    }
    document.getElementById('total').value = total;
```

Please see the screenshot[image]

Answer (score 1):

What I understand, that you want to enter the name and price of item and then by add or deduct button, perform add or subtract operation. Plus you also want to manage the Total Value.

I create a program through your screenshot. Code is written below.

```js
// Selecting the Elements from Html
Item_Name = document.getElementById("Item_Name");
var Price = document.getElementById("Price");
var Add = document.getElementById("Add");
var Deduct = document.getElementById("Deduct");
var Name_Here = document.getElementById("name_here");
var Price_Here = document.getElementById("price_here");
var Total = document.getElementById("Total");
var Total_Value = 0;

// Get and Set the values
Add.onclick = function(){
    Name_Here.innerText = Item_Name.value;
    Price_Here.innerText = Price.value;
    Total_Value += parseInt(Price.value);
    Total.innerText = Total_Value;
}
Deduct.onclick = function(){
    Name_Here.innerText = Item_Name.value;
    Price_Here.innerText = Price.value;
    Total_Value -= parseInt(Price.value);
    Total.innerText = Total_Value;
}
```

```css
.flex_container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.container{
    width: 300px;
    min-height: 220px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
}
button{
    margin: 12px 0px;
}
.Span_Header{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
input{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 8px 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="flex_container">
        <div class="container">
            <span>Item name</span><br>
            <input type="text" name="item_name" id="Item_Name" placeholder="Item name"><br>
            <span>Price</span><br>
            <input type="number" name="price" id="Price" placeholder="Price"><br>
            <button id="Add">Add</button>
            <button id="Deduct">Deduct</button>
            <div class="Span_Header">
                <span>Item name</span>
                <span>Price</span>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="Span_Header">
                <span id="name_here">Name Here</span>
                <span id="price_here">Price Here</span>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="Total_div">
                <span>Total: </span>
                <span id="Total"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please include all of your code if you would like an answer. What is priceTrim?

Are you trying to loop through a number of textbox values? If so you will have to use the querySelectorAll domElement method to loop as it returns an array type of all the text boxes , then you can specify what it is you want to do with that information in the function.

Also your if statement syntax is all wrong. You have no code block for code to perform if your testing condition returns true.

Please put in all the code and try ans explain what exactly it is you are trying to achieve? I feel like you’ve given half a story!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).